# HTTP method PUT not supported in spring boot

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, put

Good morning,
I am developing a Spring boot (latest version) application, secured with Spring security (latest version).

I am trying to make a `PUT` request from a JSP page to an Spring REST endpoint which should only return a `String` object, in particular:

**JSP code**: inside a script i am making the following AJAX request

```
<!-- change event of batch status script -->
function changeEventStatus(idEvento, statoEvento) {
    let data = {"id_evento": idEvento, "stato": statoEvento};

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/entsorgafin/events/api/cambiaStatoEvento',
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log("process terminated.");
        console.log("data collected:");
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

**Controller code**: the controller is annotated with `@RestController` and `@CrossOrigin` annotations to enable CORS requests and spring automatic management of rest requests

```
@PutMapping("/cambiaStatoEvento")
public String changeEventStatus(@RequestBody Evento evento)
{
    logger.info("API CONTROLLER - changing the status of the event with ID " + evento.getId_evento());
    

    //If the status status is not Risolto, the event will be taken in charge
    if(! evento.getStato().equals("Risolto"))
    {
        logger.info("API CONTROLLER - status of event " + evento.getId_evento() + " changed to In Lavorazione");
        eventoService.changeEventStatus(evento.getId_evento(), "In Lavorazione");
    } else
    {
        logger.info("API CONTROLLER - status of event " + evento.getId_evento() + " changed to Risolto");
        eventoService.changeEventStatus(evento.getId_evento(), "Risolto");
    }
    
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

I checked with chrome devtools and the payload is correctly encoded and sent, but Spring boot log this when I make a request:

```
2021-01-18 17:18:00.822 DEBUG 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for PUT "/accessDenied", parameters={}
2021-01-18 17:18:00.827  WARN 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported]
2021-01-18 17:18:00.828 DEBUG 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 405
2021-01-18 17:18:00.829 DEBUG 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for PUT "/error", parameters={}
2021-01-18 17:18:00.830 DEBUG 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2021-01-18 17:18:00.832 DEBUG 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-01-18 17:18:00.832 DEBUG 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Jan 18 17:18:00 CET 2021, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, trace=org.springframe (truncated)...]
2021-01-18 17:18:00.833 DEBUG 15564 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
```

Having said this, I tried `GET` requests and works just fine as expected, whereas `DELETE` and `POST` requests do not work as `PUT` ones.

Just by reading logs I think is a Spring security problem, but I can't understand what problem I am facing, I read from the Spring documentation that CORS requests are automatically managed and nothing should be done, but it is obviously not working that way.

If someone could help with what I am missing or just point to some place I can find answers as I really do not know what could be wrong here, thanks in advance.

EDIT

**Security configuration**

```
package com.entsorgafin.sr002EagleCloud.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredFieldsWarningInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    //Dependency Injection
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Qualifier("securityUserDetailService")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    /**
     * Manages the encoder to save passwords in the DB
     * not in plain text
     *
     * @return PasswordEncoder object
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    /**
     * Manages the configuration of the Authentication manager with
     * user credentials and roles.
     * <p>
     * The AuthenticationManager processes any authentication request.
     *
     * @param auth AuthenticationManagerBuilder object
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    
    /**
     * Manages the configuration for specific http request.
     *
     * @param http HttpSecurity request
     * @throws Exception exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                //configure security for pages
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(new String[]{"/login", "/accessDenied"}).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasAnyRole('admin', 'operatore', 'ufficio tecnico', 'processista')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                //creates login form
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/accessDenied")
                .usernameParameter("id_utente").passwordParameter("password")
                //catches exceptions http 403 response
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
        
        http.requestCache().disable();
        
        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }
    
    /**
     * Manages the storage of user credentials inside database
     *
     * @return The authenticationProvider Object
     */
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider()
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver()
    {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }
}
```

Regarding `csrf` I added to the head the JSP meta tag `<sec:csrfMetaTags/>` which should take care of the `csrf` protection or at least the documentation says this.

EDIT 2

By changing the Ajax request as follows

```
<!-- change event of batch status script -->
function changeEventStatus(idEvento, statoEvento) {

    let csrfParameter = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter']").attr("content");
    let csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    let csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    let data = {};
    let headers = {};

    data[csrfParameter] = csrfToken;
    data["id_evento"] = idEvento;
    data["stato"] = statoEvento;
    headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/entsorgafin/events/api/cambiaStatoEvento',
        type: 'PUT',
        headers: headers,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log("process terminated.");
        console.log("data collected:");
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

the request is performed correctly, now the problem is how to deal with the csrf token, as Spring tries to deserialize and put it into the java object (`Evento` in this case) and give back

```
Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.entsorgafin.sr002EagleCloud.model.Evento]]
Could not resolve parameter [0] in public java.lang.String com.entsorgafin.sr002EagleCloud.controller.rest.EventsController_rest.changeEventStatus(com.entsorgafin.sr002EagleCloud.model.Evento): Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
```

The payload of the request is:

```
{_csrf: "88c27418-7d48-4d76-a6ec-d76e7a45a61a", id_evento: 50, stato: "Attivo"}
```

How can i instruct spring boot not to use the csrf token for deserialization?

Comment: This confuses me: `whereas DELETE and POST requests do not work as PUT ones`. Your logs are showing a POST request. Can you show us the POST and DELETE end-points and specify what is working/not working? To rule out Spring Security issues, can you replace `@SpringBootApplication` with `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)` and run another test? BR

Comment: check csrf token, csrf tokens only affects requests that mutate the server. If you post your security configuration we can check that.

Comment: I corrected the error, I chose the wrong log, sorry. Anyway, only GET requests works, the other are not working at all with the same log trace.

Regarding the csrf I edited the question with the security configuration.

Comment: @Roar The test with the @SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class) shows the same log as before, no changes.